# Navigation .active

Tags: html, css

I have some issues with trying to put active hover on my navigation. I've created my navigation as a div not like `<li>` so I found a solution on W3Schools but it doesn't work for me. :P

Anybody interested in helping me? Here's my code, thank you in advance.

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-right:solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
  border-left: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

p {
  font-family: "Allerta Stencil";
  font-size: 25px;
}


#header {
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: auto;
}

#navigacija {
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #089DE3;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  border-top: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
  border-bottom:  solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

.navitem {
  background: #089DE3;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



.home:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.info:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

img {
  float: right;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #089DE3;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

#p1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>

<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>HTML i CSS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jockey+One" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta+Stencil" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
 img.c1 {width:200px; height:200px;}
/*]]>*/
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<div id="navigacija">
<a class="active" href="Home.html">
<div class="navitem home"><strong>HOME</strong></div></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<div class="navitem gallery"><strong>GALLERY</strong></div>
<a href="#"></a>
<div class="navitem contact"><strong>CONTACT</strong></div>
<a href="#"></a>
<div class="navitem info"><strong>INFO</strong></div>
</div>
</div>
<h1><strong>HTML i CSS</strong></h1>
<h2>HTML</h2>
<p><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" alt="html logo" class="c1" /> HTML (engl. HyperText Markup Language, jezik za oznacavanje hiperteksta) je opisni jezik specijalno namenjen opisu veb stranica. Pomocu njega se jednostavno mogu odvojiti elementi kao sto su naslovi, paragrafi, citati i slicno. Pored toga, u HTML standard su ugradjeni elementi koji detaljnije opisuju sam dokument kao sto su kratak opis dokumenta, kljucne reci, podaci o autoru i slicno. Ovi podaci su opstepoznati kao meta podaci i jasno su odvojeni od sadrzaja dokumenta. Aktuelna verzija standarda je HTML 4.01, a sam standard odrzava Konzorcijum za Veb (W3C, World Wide Web Consortium).HTML je nastao uproscavanjem SGML (Standard Generalized Markup Language, standardizovani uopsteni jezik za oznacavanje) standarda sa svrhom opisa dokumenta koji se objavljuju na vebu.U pocetku je bio prilicno ogranicen sto se oznacavanja sadrzaja tice i pruzao je uglavnom elementarne stvari za oznacavanje i formatiranje teksta (paragrafi, naslovi, citati itd.). Kako je veb rastao tako je rasla i potreba za bogatijim sadrzajem te je u tom smeru razvijan i HTML standard. Tada su standardu dodate elementi za opis tabela, slika, slojeva, napredno formatiranje teksta itd.Svi HTML dokumenti bi trebalo da pocinju sa definicijom tipa dokumenta DTD, Document Type Definition koji pregledacu definise po kom standardu je dokument pisan.Ovaj kod govori pregledacu da je dokument pisan po strogom HTML 4.01 standardu. Ovaj konkretan standard iskljucuje koriscenje prezentacionih elemenata da bi se sto bolje odvojila prezentacija od sadrzaja.</p>
<h2>CSS</h2>
<p><img src="http://www.blackbirdsolutions.com.au/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/blog/css3-logo.png?itok=r8kt8WZA" alt="css logo" class="c1" />CSS (engl. Cascading Style Sheets) je jezik formatiranja pomocu kog se definise izgled elemenata veb-stranice. Prvobitno, HTML je sluzio da definise kompletan izgled, strukturu i sadrzaj veb-stranice, ali je od verzije 4.0 HTML-a uveden CSS koji bi definisao konkretan izgled, dok je HTML ostao u funkciji definisanja strukture i sadrzaja.CSS je u odredjenoj formi postojao jos u zacecima SGML-a 1970-ih godina. Kako je HTML postajao komplikovaniji, davao je sve vise mogucnosti za definiciju izgleda elemenata, ali je istovremeno postajao necitljiviji i tezi za odrzavanje. Razliciti brauzeri su prikazivali dokumente na razlicite nacine, i postojala je potreba za doslednom tehnikom definisanja prikaza elemenata na stranici. Da bi se ovo postiglo, devet razlicitih metoda je predlozeno na zvanicnom forumu W3C-a. Od devet, dve metode su izabrane kao temelj onoga sto je kasnije postalo CSS: CHSS (engl. Cascading HTML Style Sheets) i SSP (engl. Stream-based Style Sheet Proposal). Prvo je Hakon Vium Li (koji je sada sef tehnicke sluzbe kompanije Opera) predlozio CHSS u oktobru 1994, jezik koji je imao dosta slicnosti sa danasnjim CSS-om. Bert Bos je radio na brauzeru po nazivu Argo, koji je imao sopstveni nacin definisanja stilova, SSP. Li i Bos su radili zajedno da bi osnovali CSS standard (slovo H je izbaceno iz skracenice CHSS jer se CSS mogao odnositi i na druge jezike pored HTML-a).</p>
<div class="footer" id="p1"><strong>Uradio: Marko Ribic Ia</strong></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: FWIW, I don't see the point in wrapping the text in your `<a>` with a `<div>` and a `<strong>`. Use CSS to style the `<a>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you are adding the `active` class to the proper element on the page. From your code, you are adding the class to your `a` element, rather than the `div` of the menu item.

```
  <a href="Home.html">
   <div class="navitem home active"><strong>HOME</strong></div>
  </a>
```

You then need to add CSS for your `active` class:

```
.active {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Here is a fiddle with your code updated:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/rk9n242L/

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it!